# RavenDb Studio - Document Custom Columns

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

Is there a way to bind child value of complex object as a column?

I mean like this:

```
class A(){
    public B AnotherType { get; set; }
}

class B(){
    public string ShowMe { get; set; }
}
```

I need to bind

> AnotherType.ShowMe

as a column of A documents view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the studio, select choose columns:

[image]

And then add the binding using JS syntax, like so:

[image]

Comment: Dear Ayende, I Tried that even before you mention it, this is the first solution that comes to any developer mind, but sir it's not working, the outputs are all empty.

Comment: I have tested this on live-test.ravendb.net and it works.

Comment: Can you create a sample db in http://live-test.ravendb.net setup the binding as you want and try it, then post the link here?

Comment: Sir I checked live-test and as you said it's working. I'm using version #30037. could this be the reason?

Comment: Yes, please use the latest version